# Adding a column to a data frame using the output of numpy.npv function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pyspark

I am trying to use 2 columns in my pyspark data frame to calculate the Net Present Value using the numpy.npv() function.I am getting the following error

> return (values / (1+rate)**np.arange(0, len(values))).sum(axis=0)
>   TypeError: len() of unsized object

I have also unsuccessfully tried to use the numpy.npv function as udf

Requesting help to resolve this issue

```
# Creating the DataFrame
df = sc.parallelize([('a',1,100),('a',2,200),('a',3,300),('a',4,400), 
('a',5,500),('a',6,600),('b',1,23),('b',2,32),('b',3,34),('b',4,55), 
('b',5,43)]).toDF(['Name','yr','cash'])
df.show()

# Loading the requisite packages
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, collect_list
import numpy as np
w = (Window.partitionBy('Name').orderBy(col('yr').desc()).rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))

df = df.withColumn('cash_list', collect_list('cash').over(w))    
df.show(truncate=False)
df = df.withColumn('discount_rate', lit(0.3))

#calculate npv
df = df.withColumn('npv_value', np.npv(df.discount_rate, df.cash_list))
```

Comment: Let's say for `Name=1 yr=1`, do you want 600/(1.3)**5 + 500/(1.3)**4 + ...200/(1.3)**1 + 100/(1.3)**0? or the other was around? By the way you cannot use `np.npv` this way. You have to use a `UDF` for that.

Comment: Correct! That is what I am trying to achieve. I thought the NPV function would do that for me. But clearly I am way off. 

I tried the UDF way. Re wrote the function as follows

@udf(returnType=DoubleType())
def calc_npv_value(rate, values):
    values = np.asarray(values)
    return (values / (1+rate)**np.arange(1,len(values)+1)).sum(axis=0)

Comment: but still run into errors. Will be very helpful if you can assist with the UDF approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code provided by the `OP`, we get the following `DataFrame` -

```
df.show(truncate=False)
+----+---+----+------------------------------+-------------+
|Name|yr |cash|cash_list                     |discount_rate|
+----+---+----+------------------------------+-------------+
|b   |5  |43  |[43]                          |0.3          |
|b   |4  |55  |[43, 55]                      |0.3          |
|b   |3  |34  |[43, 55, 34]                  |0.3          |
|b   |2  |32  |[43, 55, 34, 32]              |0.3          |
|b   |1  |23  |[43, 55, 34, 32, 23]          |0.3          |
|a   |6  |600 |[600]                         |0.3          |
|a   |5  |500 |[600, 500]                    |0.3          |
|a   |4  |400 |[600, 500, 400]               |0.3          |
|a   |3  |300 |[600, 500, 400, 300]          |0.3          |
|a   |2  |200 |[600, 500, 400, 300, 200]     |0.3          |
|a   |1  |100 |[600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100]|0.3          |
+----+---+----+------------------------------+-------------+
```

OP wants to calculate [`Net Present Value (NPV)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.npv.html) and for that he wants to use `UDF`. For `Name=a yr=1` the NPV is as follows -

> 600/(1.3)^5 + 500/(1.3)^4 + 400/(1.3)^3 + 300/(1.3)^2 + 200/(1.3)^1 + 100/(1.3)

```
# Creating a function and it's corresponding UDF
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
def calculate_npv(cash_list,rate):
   # Reverse the List
   cash_list = cash_list[::-1]
   return float(np.npv(rate,cash_list))
calculate_npv = udf(calculate_npv,FloatType())

# Applying the UDF to the DataFrame below
df = df.withColumn('NPV',calculate_npv('cash_list','discount_rate'))
df.show(truncate=False)
+----+---+----+------------------------------+-------------+----------+
|Name|yr |cash|cash_list                     |discount_rate|NPV       |
+----+---+----+------------------------------+-------------+----------+
|b   |5  |43  |[43]                          |0.3          |43.0      |
|b   |4  |55  |[43, 55]                      |0.3          |88.07692  |
|b   |3  |34  |[43, 55, 34]                  |0.3          |101.75148 |
|b   |2  |32  |[43, 55, 34, 32]              |0.3          |110.27037 |
|b   |1  |23  |[43, 55, 34, 32, 23]          |0.3          |107.823364|
|a   |6  |600 |[600]                         |0.3          |600.0     |
|a   |5  |500 |[600, 500]                    |0.3          |961.53845 |
|a   |4  |400 |[600, 500, 400]               |0.3          |1139.645  |
|a   |3  |300 |[600, 500, 400, 300]          |0.3          |1176.65   |
|a   |2  |200 |[600, 500, 400, 300, 200]     |0.3          |1105.1154 |
|a   |1  |100 |[600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100]|0.3          |950.08875 |
+----+---+----+------------------------------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. I will try to figure what I did wrong. minus the reversing of the list, I had pretty much done the same. One difference I see is that the input to UDF is (discount_rate, cash_list)

Comment: this has been some very useful learning you have given me. Many thanks and appreciate it!

Comment: I hope all goes the best for you.